# Как получить доступ к экземплярам другого класса?

Tags: java

У меня есть `public class Human`, в котором находится `private int age;`.
Также, имеется `public class Student extends Human`, который соответственно наследует класс `Student`.

У меня есть класс группа.

```
public class Group implements Comparable<Group>  {
    private Student[] group = new Student[10];
}
```

Я хочу сделать сортировку по возрасту `private int age`.

Как мне достучаться до экземпляра `age` класса `Human` или `Student`? Пока что, пытаясь сделать подобное:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Group o)
{
    return o.age() - this.age();
}
```

вылетает ошибка `The method age() is undefined for the type Group`

Comment: this.age() это метод,  а this.age переменная, удалите скобки, а лучше напишите геттер и используйте его , для доступа к полю

Comment: Точно!
Но теперь соответственно не видит переменную..
"  age cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field ".
Та же фигня с геттером  " getAge cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field " , геттер написан.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `int age` является `private`, поэтому тут 2 пути:

1)В классе `Human` заменить `private int age` на `public int age` и метод `compareTo` изменить так

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Group o){
    return o.age - this.age;
}
```

2)В классе `Human` создать метод

```
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}
```

и метод `compareTo` изменить так

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Group o){
    return o.getAge() - this.age;
}
```